# What does 決め決め mean?

Tags: words

> 個人的にこういうカチッ！っと**決め決め**の男性がタイプです

It's a woman commenting a picture of a young man.

I think 決め決めの means something like "determined", "resolved". It doesn't seem to be a real word because I can't find it. I've found 決め that means "agreement" and I've thought that maybe she doubles it to add emphasis, but I don't know how much "agreement" and "determination" are related...

Also, doesn't カチッ！と require a verb to be attached to 男性? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This 決め決め (also written as キメキメ in katakana) is from 決める in the following sense:

> ##### [決める](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%B1%BA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B)
>
> Ichidan verb, Transitive verb
> 6. to dress up; to dress to kill; to dress to the nines

> ##### [決める](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%B1%BA%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B/)
>
> ６ かっこうよくぴったりした服装をする。「紺のスーツで―・める」

決める refers to neatly wearing attire such as a suit, uniform, costume or dress, or applying makeup suitable for some important occasion. It often refers to wearing formal attire, but depending on the situation, it can also apply to high-end clothes for a date, cute stage costumes, or even a Santa Claus outfit. 決まってるね means "You look sharp / put together!"

And 決め決め is a mimetic word that describes this. 決め決めの男性 alone could broadly apply to people who are always dressed like Instagram influencers or fashion magazines, but since it also has カチッと, I imagine mean who are dressed in formal attire or [something like this](https://www.leon.jp/magazine).

カチッと is indeed an adverb, but 決め決め is a no-adjective here, and an adverb can modify a (no-)adjective, too. カチッと決め決めの男性 (adverb-adjective-noun) is structurally the same as とても面白い本.

Comment: Aren't の-adjectives just nouns? 決め決め is a noun in Japanese, isn't it?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi Yes, but somehow even such nouns are sometimes modified by an adverb, for example まったく普通の人 (completely ordinary person), やや緑色の水 (slightly green water).

Comment: Can I do that with any noun?

Comment: @Haragurodanshi No, an adverb can modify some descriptive nouns, but I don't know precise rules.